# What exactly Does this code do?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

```
/*
No source for you!
*//
/.source.replace(/.{7}/g,function(w){
document.write(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(w.replace(/ /g,'0').replace(/   /g,'1'),2)))});
```

I don't know javascript this well but this looks like an encryption of some sort, but I believe that the comment is somehow related, Sorry for my little knowledge on decryption, thankyou!

Comment: Wow, the syntax highlighting has a hard time: syntax error.

Comment: Well this isnt just some code, it is hiding a masive source code, And I wish I knew how so I can use it on my website!

Answer (score 4):

This is quite cute. It splits the "source" into 7 character long substrings (`.{7}`) and replaces certain whitespace characters with `0` or `1`, then interprets these `0` and `1` strings as binary number (`parseInt(.., 2)`) and turns them into a character (`String.fromCharCode`). The whitespace source itself is written as a regex literal (`/   /`).

Essentially, all source code is encoded as "invisible" whitespace and this piece of code turns it back into the actual source code.

Since the source is written back into the DOM where you can then read it, it's somewhat useless for actual "protection"; but all obfuscation is ultimately useless. You cannot hide Javascript code, since then the browser couldn't execute it. If the browser must execute it, it must be publicly visible somehow, somewhere. But again, it's *cute*.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that _ASCII_ encoding uses _7-bits_, in case you were wondering if it was an arbitrary number

Comment: 0.0 Thankyou , this is exactly what I believed it was, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The above code will replace space by 0 or 1 hen interprets these 0 and 1 strings as binary number and turns them into a character

Comment: Thankyou thats interesting!

Comment: And how does it know when its 0 or 1 ?